# Slow Download Speed only through wireless

Tags: wireless-networking, speed, connection

I noticed my internet has been really slow for past week, so i did a [speed test](http://www.speedtest.net) and got a 0.50 Mb/s download speed when my real speed is 6 Mb/s.
I performed this test from my computer via wireless (my wireless router is Linksys WRT54G2 V1 running the latest original firmware Version 1.0.04).

I did the same test using a wired connection and got my 6 Mb/s.
Via wireless I am getting a 54.0 Mbps connection speed and an excellent signal strength.
I tried changing the wireless channel right after monitoring with Network Stumbler that my wireless channel wasn't receiving any interference and it wasn't, but i changed it anyways just to test).

So.. what could be the issue here? Is my router defective? Is there something else i could try?
I was getting 6 Mb/s over wireless before and just this week i noticed this problem...

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: Your router is probably not defective. Check your network card drivers. You should be getting at least 20Mbps on the 802.11g.

Comment: @Randolph Potter: nice suggestion. i just updated the drivers to the latest, got same results. i just checked the only other notebook in the house and oddly enough it is not getting a 54 Mbps speed, but a 5 Mbps instead. Weird.

Comment: IMO, dedicated speedtests aren't very accurate. My way of testing network speed is to download a large (>100MB) file from a representative server (a copy of Linux, an Adobe program trial, etc. are all fine) and check the download speed in the middle of the download.

Comment: The speed is still slow if you use the notebook at 1 or 2 meters from the router? Did you change the router's place or something close to it recently?

Comment: @laurent-rpnet: Actually the notebook is a few inches away from the router. Nothing has changed recently

Comment: @digitxp well, even though they are not accurate i shouldnt be getting a 0.50 Mb/s download speed and doing it though a wired connection a minute later does download at 6 Mbps

Comment: Have you tried moving files over your local network? Try large files (>100MB) and see what speeds you get. The Task Manager's network graph can add columns for traffic per interval, to give you an idea.

Comment: You probably did that already but just in case unplug the router (from power) and turn it on again. Wireless routers usually have some parameters to adjust like Transmit Power, RTS Threshold, Fragmentation. I think it could be good to check if they are correct or reset them to default.